# Detach ApplicationGateway

Tags: azure

In VMSS/Networking/NetworkInterface/LocadBalancing I have 2 LoadBalancers (which points to one) and ApplicationGateway (which points to nonexistent apllication gateway), so question is how to remove/detach ApplicationGateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems is solved, steps:

1. Create new AG in same dev group and region and name as AG in VMSS
2. Add backend pool to this AG (name should be same as name in VMSS/Networking/NetworkInterface/LocadBalancing)
3. Add empty backend pool with one rule (it could be pool which points to some random ip address)
4. Wait ~10 minutes
5. Remove backend pool created in second step
6. Run upgrade command for all (in my case just one) virtual machins in VMSS
7. Remove AG created in first step